Show that $\int_{\mathbb R^d}fd\mu=\sum_{x\in C}f(x)$ for countable $C\subset R^d$
Problem. Let $C$ be a countable subset of $\mathbb R^d$ and $\mu$ be the counting measure on $\mathbb R^d$ i.e., $$\mu(A)=\#(A\cap C),\qquad A\in \mathcal B(\mathbb R^d).$$
Show that for a measurable $f:\mathbb R^d\rightarrow \mathbb R$, $$\int_{\mathbb R^d}fd\mu=\sum_{x\in C}f(x),$$
whenever either the integral on the LHS is defined or $$\min\left(\sum_{x\in C}f^+(x),\sum_{x\in C}f^-(x)\right)<\infty.$$

Attempt. For the first 2 cases, I have proved that the result holds. I'm unable to proceed with case 3. Case 4 follows simply from case 3 by writing $f=f^+-f^-$ excluding the case when $\infty-\infty$ is reached.
Case 1. $f$ is a simple indicator function i.e., for some set $X\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R^d),~f=\mathbb I_X$.
Case 2. $f$ is a simple, non-negative function. Then, for $X_i\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R^d)$, $f$ can be written as $\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i\mathbb I_{X_i}$ for some $\alpha_i>0$ and $X_i\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R^d)$. (proof using step 1)
Case 3. $f$ is non-negative. Then, we can find non-negative simple functions $f_n$ such that $0\le f_n\uparrow f$. It follows that $0\le \int f_nd\mu\uparrow\int fd\mu$. Using step 2, $\int_{\mathbb R^d}f_n d\mu=\sum_{x\in C}f_n(x)$. We know that the LHS increases to $\int fd\mu$. Enough to show that RHS increases to $\sum_{x\in C}f(x)$.
How do I proceed for this step? Is my method correct?
Case 4. $f$ is non necessarily non-negative.

You can actually do this directly from the definition, see here

For Case 3. We can proceed as follows. Let $f$ be a non-negative, measurable function. Set
$$
    f_n(x) = \sum_{k = 1}^n f(c_k) \cdot 1\{x = c_k\} = \begin{cases}
f(c_k), \text{ if } \exists k \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}, x = c_k\\ 0 \text{, otherwise} \end{cases}
$$
Here, I denote the countable set $C$ as $C = \{c_1, c_2, \ldots\}$.
Then, by case 2,
$$
   \int f_n d\mu = \sum_{x \in C} f_n(x) = \sum_{k = 1}^n f(c_k) \uparrow \sum_{x \in C} f(x)
$$
Now, observe that $f_n \uparrow f \cdot 1_C$, and by the monotone convergence theorem,
$$
   \int f_n d\mu \uparrow \int f \cdot 1_C d\mu
$$
Thus,
$$
    \int f \cdot 1_C d\mu = \sum_{x \in C} f(x)
$$
Now, what left to do is to show
$$
    \int f \cdot 1_{C^c} d\mu = 0
$$
which is simple, as
$$
    \int 1_A \cdot 1_{C^c}d\mu = \mu(A \cap C^c)=\#(A\cap C^c \cap C) = 0 \ \forall \text{ measurable set } A
$$

Here, you found a sequence of non-negative simple functions $f_n$ with increasing limit $f$ only for points in $C$. This was important because the result proved for step 2 holds only for $x\in C$. As a result, it became important to show what happens for $x$ not in $C$ as the LHS (integral in claim) is defined over $R^d$ not limited to $C$. Is this the right motivation behind proving that the integral is $0$ everywhere outside $C$ for this step?

@reyna Yes, what I've shown is $$ \int f \cdot 1_C d\mu = \sum_{x \in C} f(x) $$ But the problem claims that $$ \int f d\mu = \sum_{x \in C} f(x) $$ which means we have to show $$ \int f 1_{C^c} d\mu = 0 $$ as $$ f = f \cdot 1_C + f \cdot 1_{C^c} $$

Using "any non-negative function $f$ can be written as an increasing limit of a sequence of non-negative simple functions $f_n$" I have $$0\le f_n\uparrow f.$$ Then, it follows that $$0\le\int f_nd\mu \uparrow fd\mu.$$  From step 2 and by Monotone convergence theorem, $$\int f_nd\mu=\sum_{x\in C}f_n(x)\uparrow \sum_{x\in C}f(x).$$ Hence, $$\int fd\mu=\sum_{x\in C}f(x).$$I followed the same procedure as your solution but did not need to specify the form of $f_n$ or consider what happens outside $C$. If there are errors, kindly point them out

@reyna The problem here is that, how can you justify the interchange of limit and summation in $$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{x \in C} f_n(x) = \sum_{x \in C} \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n(x) = \sum_{x \in C} f(x) $$ ? It is not possible to justify when you don't know the form of $f_n$ and $C$ is a countable set

How does $\int 1_A\cdot 1_{C^c} d\mu = 0$ imply $\int f \cdot 1_{C^c} d\mu = 0$

@reyna You prove it by the same procedure: Indicator function -> Simple function -> Nonnegative function
